# Keeping text position in the exact same place for viewport sizes

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to keep every single thing in my code in the exact same position? For example, my text is positioned with padding and a percentage value and when I change the viewport size, the text moves (probably to fit the padding) Is there any way to change this and keep my text in a fixed position at any viewport size?

Comment: A percentage value is relative to the parent container. As the size of the parent container changes, the calculated value of the percentage will change as well. If you don't want that, then use a different [length unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

Comment: I’d need to know more of what you’re asking for to give the best answer. Are you trying to keep it in the same place in a div? Are you trying to keep in the same place on the page? Do you want the text to stay the same size or scale relative to the page too? Lots of options here. 

Could you provide a demo and some code so we can better answer?

Comment: What does 'in the exact same place' mean for e.g. a page shown on a wide screen versus one shown on a vertically held mobile phone? Please explain a bit more - perhaps a couple of images would help - and put the code you have tried so far into your question.

Comment: @davidleininger I am trying to make sure my text doesn't go onto the next line. My website code is at https://jsfiddle.net/2nrpxm5j/2/. And my screen resolution is 1920x1049 and I am trying to make it look the same on every other screen size (will format for phone later) as it looks on my screen, like this site made on wix: evantso.wixsite.com/pandorax

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are ways to keep elements in your code in the exact same position regardless of the viewport size, like with position Absolute, Fixed Positioning, Use Fixed Units, Media Queries.

Let me give you an example:

Here is the html:

```
<div class="container">
  <p class="fixed-text">Your fixed text here</p>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.container {
  position: relative; /* This is required to use absolute positioning inside */
  width: 100%; /* Set the desired width of the container */
  height: 300px; /* Set the desired height of the container */
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.fixed-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px; /* Adjust the top distance as needed */
  left: 20px; /* Adjust the left distance as needed */
}
```

By using absolute positioning with fixed pixel values, the text will stay at the specified position regardless of the viewport size or device used.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I could still change the fixed position for just phone specifically though right?

Comment: Yeah, with the help of media query.

Comment: Wait actually, when I resize my website, the text still moves to the next line because of the size shrinking. Is it possible for it not to do that?

Comment: try to small the font size of your text. If text is more than the space, it will definitely break. If you are still willing to do it, then use white-space: no-wrap;  on your paragraph.

Comment: Is it possible for it to stay wrapped in a certain way without breaking?

Comment: No, text will at least take its space which it wants, wrap means it will go the next line, by applying no wrap it will not break.

Answer (score 0):

The fixed div will always be the same size, just use the min property.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .container {
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      background:#efefef;
      display:flex;
      align-items:center;
      justify-content:center;
    }

    .container .fixed-position {
      min-width:200px;
      min-height:200px;
      background:red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="fixed-position"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```